# Is there a "not equal to" selector in Prototype js?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have this function in Jquery which basically says when you click on the ID "MyID" do a fadetoggle of all the li tags where the class is not equal to "nav":

```
$("#MyID").click(function () {
    $('li[class!="nav"]').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
});
```

Is there a way to do this in Prototype js? Specifically is there a way to use a selector that selects a class != (not equal to) something?

Comment: jQuery does support the not selector, but the problem you have is that if you have `<li class="nav something else">` it'll still be selected because `"nav"` and `"nav something else"` aren't the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
     $("MyID").click(function () {
              $$('li :not(.nav)').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
      });
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I was naughty and updated it, but basically, it's really close. In prototype $ only works with a single element and against IDs (so no need for the '#' modifier), and $$ is used for css. Note that the "pattern" for observing events is also $('MyID").observe('click', function() ....

Answer (score 2):

From the [Prototype documentation](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/):

> #### Supported CSS syntax
>
> ...
>
> - Attribute selectors: the full CSS 2.1 set of `[attr]`, `[attr=value]`, `[attr~=value]` and `[attr|=value]`. It also supports `[attr!=value]`. If the value you're matching against includes a space, be sure to enclose the value in quotation marks (`[title="Hello World!"]`).

So the 'not equal to' comparator still works, you only need to remember to use the  [`$$`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/) function.

However as [tylermwashburn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/612367/tylermwashburn) points out it can be different with class names.

```
Event.observe('MyID', 'click', function() {
    Effect.multiple($$('li:not(.nav)'), function(element){
        Effect.toggle(element, 'appear');
    });
});
```

<sub>The selector `:not(.nav)` is the same as `:not(class~=nav)` as [explained here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)</sub>